# Why store regular expression patter in var

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to software development and wondering if there are any differences, performance reasons for storing regular expression patterns in variables as illustrated in the examples below:

example 1:

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var patt = /Hello/g;
var result = patt.test(str);
```

example 2:

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var result = /Hello/g.test(str);
```

Comment: There aren't any performance reasons to choose one over the other. It all comes down to personal choice around formatting and readability.

Answer (score 0):

I think that that has something to do with the readability of the code, for example you might have a regular expression that has too many characters and defining it as a variable can make your codebase clean... if you are interested in regular expression then you might consider checking how compilers are made especially Lexing part of a compiler..

So to summarize this I don't think there's performance benefit but that is meant to improve readability of the code

Answer (score 0):

There is no measurable difference between the two. You can test the performance of your example 1 and example2 by running each 1,000,000 times like this:

```js
   function measure(message, times, callback) {
    var start = new Date();
    for(var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        callback();
    }
    var end = new Date();
    console.log(message + ': ' + ((end - start) / 1000) + ' sec')
}

measure('example 1', 1000000, function() {
    var str = "Hello world!";
    var patt = /Hello/g;
    var result = patt.test(str);
});

measure('example 2', 1000000, function() {
    var str = "Hello world!";
    var result = /Hello/g.test(str);
});
```

Running the code snippet multiple times you can see that sometimes the example 1 is slightly faster, sometimes example 2. Unlike C in VxWorks, JavaScript does not run hard realtime, e.g. the garbage collection and other language & OS overhead overshadows the way you use your regex examples.